# 3kala-Sandhyavandanam - multiple queries

Tags: rituals, sandhyavandanam

**Namaste**
I read most of the questions on this portal about *Sandhyavandanam* but somehow my questions are not answered.
I am recovering from lack of knowledge of these rites over years, and with covid, rediscovered them. 
With many constraints in daily life to practice that I am trying to overcome, hence have been on reunderstanding journey to start practicing them.
I am given to understand that disturbances are possible in life if one forgets  NityaKarma over many years.
After my realization of this gap in *Nitya karma* to be done 3 times, I began to understand the challenge faced 
In morning time, due to earlier work life schedules,there is lot of chaos in the house and in the mind - many reasons to be mentioned here.
Hence noon and mostly evening time are the only ones where some time and peace is available.
Another constraint is small house, so presence of women during cycle time they cannot be kept in separate room.
Moreover I am at a place in North where there are no south indian pundits, nor we have had any family priest in one whole generation.
Remotely I have tried to ask these questions to priests in metro cities but there they are of the opinion that all is ok, One should do what one can. 
However I am keen to know and practice formally now, hence seeking responses here.
**a1**. What should be the timing of Sandhya Vandanam.
I request specific duration if anyone can share for all the 3 slots.
**a2**. if i am unable to perform PrAtahSandhya within morning slot, what is the prAyashchitta process?
**b1**. can i perform MAdhyanhikam directly at noon if I miss the time of PratahSandhya?
**b2**. If I cannot, what is the prayashchitta process?
**c1**. Is Brahmayajnam to be performed only after MAdhyanhikam? 
or can it be performed with PrataHSandhya/SayamSandhya?
**d1**. Many videos are on youtube, but all with disclaimer of discussing with priest for more info. where do I find such priests who can answer questions regarding the actual processes?
**d2**. Can **#SankaraMatham** cater to such queries, any such support system to asnwer such questions? 
**e1**. with women in monthly cycle, and there being only one room which can be used by male member, room is multipurpose, what best are the niyamas to be followed? 
I hope I can get some clarity from expert sane voices here for my journey to recover myself.

Answer (score 0):

a1: answer in 24 hr format for Indian Standard Time

5:50 am  to 7:30 am
12:20 pm to 13:10 pm
17:15 pm  to 18:00 pm

a2 b1 b2:
There is no praayaschittam for sandhyavandanam lapses, as indicated by Aacharyaas. Because Sandhyavandanam just demands a devotee of purity to utter Gayatri devi mantra by mind. One need not even open mouth or do any body actions.
Second, before any yagyam or homam with AGNI the sandhyavandanam mantram must be accompanied because on such days the performer may be so tired that he may drowse without looking at Sun god.

Sandhyavandanam during PUNYA KAALAM or AAVANI AVITTAM compensates for lapses by an individual in a year.
THERE IS NOTHING TO WORRY.

But, d1 d2 and e1 - questions can be answered by specific Aacharya only or from their pravachanams. It deals with mutualism of existence/powers.

A GENERAL FACT : NON DOER IS NO VICTIM

If one cant perform Sandhyavandam by actions and mind during time slots, still the victim is not the non-doer, but those sinners living in his environment and bestowed to main Temple in his area and those seeking refuge of life with home/hut in the area MAY BE VICTIMS.

Hence, to avoid society being punished by wrath of God, Sandhyavandanam must be performed by any doer meant for it. It is very very easy to perform.

```
SANDHYA - THE PROTECTOR at DAWN
```

Society contains people of mix: feeding on both plant and animals products without gap in consumption. In such atmosphere, neglecting Sandhyavandansm may not protect society.

```
 HUMAN of natural DIVINE POWERS
```

If one lives on Cloudy MOUNTAINS or in Oceans (without feet touching land under waters) with eating habit as Vegetarian, he is exempted by Sandhyavandanam due to "Intellect of virtues by nature" TO PROTECT MUTUAL DEPENDANCIES - " Examples: Aadi Shankaraachaarya, priests of Simhaachalam " etc.